# 3 Tables, 2 Foreign Keys, Sum by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help getting the correct output.  I have a expense categories (1 table with main categories like 'Medical') and related expense subcategories (like 'exam', 'therapy', etc.).  These are tied together by pcatid and pcatid_fk.  An entry gets made to the persexpenses with a reference to both the category (pcatid_fk) and subcategory (psubcatid_fk).  My query is yielding a result where the amount for an expense shows up in each row where the category + subcategory are shown.

In this example, I have made an entry for a $500 exam in April.  Here is what the output looks like:

#### Current result

```
Category    Subcategory     Jan         Feb          April
Medical     Exam            NULL        NULL         500.000
Medical     Therapy         NULL        NULL         500.000
Medical     Test            NULL        NULL         500.000
```

and what it should look like:

#### Desired result

```
Category    Subcategory     Jan         Feb          April
Medical     Exam            NULL        NULL         500.000
Medical     Therapy         NULL        NULL         NULL
Medical     Test            NULL        NULL         NULL
```

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT Isnull(second.pcategory, 0)   AS CATEGORY,
   Isnull(third.psubcategory, 0) AS SUBCATEGORY,
   Isnull(first.jan, 0)          AS JAN,
   Isnull(first.feb, 0)          AS FEB,
   Isnull(first.mar, 0)          AS MAR,
   Isnull(first.apr, 0)          AS APR,
   Isnull(first.may, 0)          AS MAY,
   Isnull(first.jun, 0)          AS JUN,
   Isnull(first.jul, 0)          AS JUL,
   Isnull(first.aug, 0)          AS AUG,
   Isnull(first.sep, 0)          AS SEP,
   Isnull(first.oct, 0)          AS OCT,
   Isnull(first.nov, 0)          AS NOV,
   Isnull(first.dec, 0)          AS DEC,
   Isnull(first.q1, 0)           AS Q1,
   Isnull(first.q2, 0)           AS Q2,
   Isnull(first.q3, 0)           AS Q3,
   Isnull(first.q4, 0)           AS Q4,
   Isnull(first.annual, 0)       AS ANNUAL
FROM   (SELECT pcategory,
           pcatid
    FROM   sky.dbo.persexpcategories) second
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT psubcategory,
                     pcatid_fk
              FROM   sky.dbo.persexpsubcat) third
          ON second.pcatid = third.pcatid_fk
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT pcategory,
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '1' THEN pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'jan',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '2' THEN pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'feb',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '3' THEN pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'mar',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '4' THEN pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'apr',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '5' THEN pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'may',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '6' THEN pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'jun',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '7' THEN pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'jul',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '8' THEN pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'aug',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '9' THEN pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'sep',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '10' THEN
                                  pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'oct',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '11' THEN
                                  pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'nov',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) = '12' THEN
                                  pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'dec',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) BETWEEN '1' AND '3'
                                THEN
                                  pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'Q1',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) BETWEEN '4' AND '6'
                                THEN
                                  pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'Q2',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) BETWEEN '7' AND '9'
                                THEN
                                  pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'Q3',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) BETWEEN '10' AND '12'
                                THEN
                                  pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'Q4',
                     Isnull(Sum(CASE
                                  WHEN Month(pexpdate) BETWEEN '1' AND '12'
                                THEN
                                  pexpamount
                                END), 0) AS 'annual'
              FROM   sky.dbo.users
                     LEFT JOIN sky.dbo.persexpenses
                            ON userid = userid_fk
                     LEFT JOIN sky.dbo.persexpcategories
                            ON pcatid_fk = pcatid
              WHERE  userid = '1'
              GROUP  BY pcategory) first
          ON second.pcategory = first.pcategory
```

The tables/[Fields] are:

persexpenses

- [pexpid]
- [pexpdate]
- [pexpamount]
- [pcatid_fk]
- [psubcatid_fk]

persexpcategories

- [pcatid]
- [pcategory]

persexpsubcat

- [psubcatid]
- [psubcategory]
- [pcatid_fk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, I have alised the table but not sure which column is coming from which tables so in case of ambiguity you will need to use the alias with the column names as well.

```
SELECT 
   PC.pcategory                     AS CATEGORY,
   PSC.psubcategory                 AS SUBCATEGORY,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 1 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0) AS JAN,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 2 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0) AS FEB,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 3 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0) AS MAR,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 4 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0) AS APR,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 5 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0) AS MAY,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 6 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0) AS JUN,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 7 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0) AS JUL,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 8 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0) AS AUG,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 9 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0) AS SEP,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 10 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0)AS OCT,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 11 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0)AS NOV,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 12 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0)AS DEC,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 1 OR MONTH(pexpdate) = 2 OR
                MONTH(pexpdate) = 3 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0)         AS Q1,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 4 OR MONTH(pexpdate) = 5 OR
                MONTH(pexpdate) = 6 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0)         AS Q2,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 7 OR MONTH(pexpdate) = 8 OR
                MONTH(pexpdate) = 9 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0)         AS Q3,
   Isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(pexpdate) = 10 OR MONTH(pexpdate) = 11 OR
                MONTH(pexpdate) = 12 THEN pexpamount ELSE NULL END), 0)        AS Q4,
   Isnull(SUM(pexpamount), 0)       AS ANNUAL
FROM  psersexpenses P LEFT JOIN sky.dbo.persexpcategories PC
ON    P.pcatid = PC.pcatid
LEFT JOIN sky.dbo.persexpsubcat PSC
ON P.psubcatid_fk = PSC.psubcatid
GROUP BY PC.pcategory,PSC.psubcategory
```

Comment: Gave that a shot.  "ON P.pcatid = PC.pcatid" should be "ON P.pcatid_fk = PC.pcatid".  I dropped "WHERE userid='1'" since we aren't bringing in that table in your re-write (fine for now).  Unfortunately I still get the same result with the amount showing up in every row.

Comment: If you could give more details about the columns from all the tables that might help to get to the issue. and as I mentioned in my answer Im only guessing on joins as I do have the table structures available.

Comment: psersexpenses has most of the information.  persexpcategories and persexpsubcat simply have the names of the categories/subcategories ties to an id.  So pcatid "1", category "Medical" in persexpcategories.  Or psubcatid "1", subcategory "Exam" in persexpsubcat

Comment: right I joined the tables in the wrong order then, In from clause FROM psersexpenses LEFT JOIN Then other tables and so on ...

Comment: Got it.  That seems to have worked.  I will put in a couple more entries then come back and check 'answered'